# Form - Listing another resource's objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I made an association between two resources , sports and activities, a activity has one sport, and wat the creation of the activity i want the user to be able to select the sport which is associated to that activity, so i wanted to make a select at the form and the possible values of that select would be all the existing sport's , then i would save the id of that chosen sport  in a sport_id variable.

```
<div class="field">
      <%= f.label "Choose the sport:" %><br>
      <%= f.select [LIST WITH ALL SPORTS] ,:sport_id %>
      <%= link_to "Sport doens't exist yet?", new_sport_path %>
    </div>
```

Basically i'm trying to do something like this, i just dont know what should i write where it says [LIST WITH ALL SPORTS]... Anyway , thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% sport_options = options_from_collection_for_select(Sport.all.sort 
{ |a,b| a.name <=> b.name }, :id, :name, selected: params[:sport_id]) %>

<%= f.select(:sport_id, category_options, {prompt: 'Select Sport'},
{prompt: 'Select Sport', include_blank: false, class: "nameyourclasshere" }) %>
```

Given that your Sport model has column named `name`, else switch to the title you use to describe the sport.